# Scrolling Jank. Unknown Anonymous function in Chrome Profiler

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to identify the cause of some scrolling jank in my application.

It appears to be related to this anonymous function that is taking up the majority of time. However I am unable to find it. Is this garbage collection?

Any help identifying what is calling this method or how to find the actual code being run by the anonymous function would be appreciated.

[image: chrome profiler]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the **JS Profile** option enabled on your Timeline recording? This provides a more detailed view of exactly which JS functions were called.

If you click on **(anonymous function)**, the **Summary** section of DevTools provides a way for you to jump to the source code of the function. It's the blue link in the screenshot below.

[image: summary]

Comment: Using the timeline instead of the profile gave me the insight that I needed that it was caused by Recalculate Style, and Layout in the browser.